# Will there be any conflicts if I have Prettier extension and Prettier NPM package?

Tags: prettier, formatter

I currently have Prettier extension (v10.1.0) installed, I would like to try and install the NPM package version (v3.0.3) of Prettier, reason is that I want to use the CLI command to format a bunch of files in my project

```
prettier . --write
```

I am unsure if the extension counterpart can do this independently. And if I can understand this correctly, both Prettier extension and NPM package share the same settings as I have in my `settings.json`?